# Using Gulp and minified CSS/JS

Tags: html, css, gulp

I recently started using Gulp to autoprefix, minifycss and minify my JS.  Right now, all the files that get autoprefixed, minified are sitting in a dist folder.  Is there a way I can point my html file to these minified versions without manually retyping the following :

```
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

to :

```
<script src="dist/custom.min.js"></script>
```

back and forth?

Right now, when I develop, I edit about 5 to 10 css and JS files but when I edit them, it's obviously in the unminified, unautoprefixed version.  I'm sure that's not how developers do it so I'm guessing there's a step that I'm missing...

Comment: "manually retyping the to:" .. what does that mean exactly . Not quite sure what you are looking to achieve but you might want to check out [wiredep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wiredep)

Comment: when deploying this, he wants to automatically replace the url to 1 js with the minified version of the js. -- thats what I got here

Comment: have you heard about `gulp-inject`, that should fit the bill, its not like it would edit the path.. but then you should inject minified/non-minified both paths using `gulp-inject`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/). From that article:

> Basically it's a way to map a combined/minified file back to an unbuilt state. When you build for production, along with minifying and combining your JavaScript files, you generate a source map which holds information about your original files. When you query a certain line and column number in your generated JavaScript you can do a lookup in the source map which returns the original location. Developer tools (currently WebKit nightly builds, Google Chrome, or Firefox 23+) can parse the source map automatically and make it appear as though you're running unminified and uncombined files.

[gulp-sourcemaps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps) is what you will need to use. You don't mention which gulp plugins you are using, but there's a good chance that they [have support for source maps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support).

Here's a simple example of how you would use it:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('minify', function() {
    gulp.src('src/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())    // Initialize the source maps.
        .pipe(minify())             // Do your minification, concatenation, etc.
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())   // Write the source maps.
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));   // Write the minified files.
});
```

Just make sure that the original unminified files are also being server by your web server so that the browser can download them.

This also has the added advantage that when you are testing your webpage at development time, you're actually running the minified code that you will end up deploying.

Comment: He's not asking how to generate minified files, but how to include minified files after build without manually edit.

Comment: I know, indeed. The root cause here, is OP's dev env is not well designed. He could have included the minified version and debug with sourcemap. However, he didn't. I don't know why but maybe there's a reason. For now, I don't know whether he has effort to refactor his project, then my answer is the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the **gulp-replace** plugin, write a task, something like this:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace')
gulp.task('adoptDist', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.dest + '/www/**/*.html', { base: paths.dest })
        .pipe(replace(/src="js\/(.+?)\.js"/g, function(match, $1) {
            return 'src="dist/' + $1 + '.min.js"'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest))
});
```